# SQLite Database Force Closing due to Syntax Error

Tags: android-sqlite

I am trying to insert into the SQLite Database but it keeps on force closing every time I run my program on the emulator. I think it has something to due with my syntax of my database creation but I have triple checked it and can't find my error. The only other thing I can think of is if I have to add something to the manifest to properly run a SQlite database.

Below is my code for my helper class.

```
public class dbhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "swimmers";
    public static final String TABLE_SWIMMERS = "sfd table";

    public static final String C_ID = "id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String TEAM = "team";
    public static final String NOTES = "notes";

    public static final int VERSION = 1;

    public dbhelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        String createdb = "create table " + TABLE_SWIMMERS + "(" + C_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME + " text, " + TEAM + " text, " + NOTES + " text); ";
        db.execSQL(createdb);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE_SWIMMERS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //add new entry
    void addSwimmer(Swimmer swimmer){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(NAME, swimmer.getname());
        values.put(TEAM, swimmer.getteam());
        values.put(NOTES, swimmer.getnotes());

        db.insert(TABLE_SWIMMERS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    //Getting single swimmer
    Swimmer getSwimmer(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SWIMMERS, new String[] { C_ID, NAME, TEAM, NOTES}, C_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor !=null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Swimmer swimmer = new Swimmer (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), null);
        return swimmer;
    }

    public int updateSwimmer(Swimmer swimmer){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(NAME, swimmer.getname());
        values.put(TEAM, swimmer.getteam());
        values.put(NOTES, swimmer.getnotes());

        return db.update(TABLE_SWIMMERS, values, C_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(swimmer.getID()) });        
    }

    //delete single contact
    public void deleteSwimmer(Swimmer swimmer){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_SWIMMERS, C_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(swimmer.getID()) });        
        db.close();
    }

    //get contacts count
    public int getSwimmersCount(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SWIMMERS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

Below is my Swimmer class that I made and I am trying to insert a Swimmer into the database.

```
public class Swimmer {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;
String _team;
String _notes;


public Swimmer(int id, String name, String team, String notes){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._team = team;
    this._notes = notes;
}

public Swimmer(String name, String team, String notes){
    this._name = name;
    this._team = team;
    this._notes = notes;
}

public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

public String getname(){
    return this._name;
}

public void setname(String name){
    this._name = name;
}

public String getteam(){
    return this._team;
}

public void setteam(String team){
    this._team = team;
}

public String getnotes(){
    return this._notes;
}

public void setnotes(String notes){
    this._notes = notes;
}
}
```

Here is my code to open and insert into the database.

```
public class CreateNewSwimmerProfile extends Activity {

private dbhelper db;

private final String TAG = "Create New Profile";

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{       
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sfdmain, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("createProfileActivity", "Intent Text");

    setContentView(R.layout.createprofile);
    Intent createprofileintent = getIntent();
    db = new dbhelper(this);
}

public void btn_CLICK_addswimmer (View w)
{   
    Log.i("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");      

    String name,team,notes;

    EditText nameIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
    EditText teamIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_team);
    EditText notesIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_notes);

    name = nameIn.getText().toString();
    team = teamIn.getText().toString();
    notes = notesIn.getText().toString();

    Swimmer test = new Swimmer(name, team, notes);
    db.addSwimmer(test);
}

public void btn_CLICK_cancel (View b)
{
        Log.i(TAG, "start create new profile activity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SFDMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

And here are my errors when I try to insert the swimmer.

```
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at                                                                         java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  ... 11 more
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table sfd table(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, team text, notes text);
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.sfd.swimming.feedback.display.system.dbhelper.onCreate(dbhelper.java:35)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.sfd.swimming.feedback.display.system.dbhelper.addSwimmer(dbhelper.java:48)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.sfd.swimming.feedback.display.system.CreateNewSwimmerProfile.btn_CLICK_addswimmer(CreateNewSwimmerProfile.java:50)
11-27 08:58:36.150: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  ... 14 more
11-27 08:58:36.420: D/dalvikvm(643): GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 4% free 8241K/8519K, paused 22ms+33ms, total 304ms
11-27 08:58:38.680: I/Process(643): Sending signal. PID: 643 SIG: 9
```

ANY help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table is a Keyword for SQLite. Try to change your variable TABLE_SWIMMERS from `TABLE_SWIMMERS = "sfd table";` to `TABLE_SWIMMERS = "sfd";` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :) Now, I am trying to write an activity that will display only the name of the swimmer at first and then when you click on the name, it displays the rest of the swimmer information.

Comment: do you have any advice on where to start?

Comment: i think i would generate two seperate activities, the first with a ListView, with an onclick-event passing a Parameter with the swimmerobject to the second activity where you can show the rest of the swimmer information.